# Securing ActiveMQ Webconsole with LDAP

Tags: authentication, ldap, activemq-classic, web-console

I am using AMQ 5.16.2. I have already configured a secured connection (HTTPS) for the AMQ webconsole.
Now I am trying to secure the webconsole authentification with LDAP. Thus, I have followed this blog:

https://workhorseintegrations.com/2020/05/14/securing-activemq-console-with-ldap/

I have adapted the **login.config** as shown below (adding startTLS and credentialConfig as parameter)

```
 activemq-ldap {
  org.ldaptive.jaas.LdapLoginModule required
      debug=true
      storePass="true"
      ldapUrl="ldaps://ad:***/"
      bindDn="adbind"
      bindCredential="****"
      baseDn="******"
      useStartTLS="true"
      credentialConfig="{/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/root-ca-cert.pem}"  
      subtreeSearch=true
      userFilter="(sAMAccountName={user})";
  org.ldaptive.jaas.LdapRoleAuthorizationModule required
      useFirstPass="true"
      ldapUrl="ldaps://ad:***/"
      bindDn="adbind"
      bindCredential="****"
      baseDn="****"
      useStartTLS="true"
      credentialConfig="{/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/root-ca-cert.pem}" 
      subtreeSearch=true
      roleFilter="(&(objectClass=group)(sAMAccountName=Test-Users)(member=CN={user},OU=***-Nutzer,OU=Benutzer,OU=***,DC=***,DC=****,DC=***))"
      defaultRole="user"
      roleAttribute="cn";
};
/** Default configuration **/
activemq {
    org.apache.activemq.jaas.PropertiesLoginModule required
        org.apache.activemq.jaas.properties.user="users.properties"
        org.apache.activemq.jaas.properties.group="groups.properties";
};
```

The AMQ Webconsole is running but I cannot login to the webconsole page. I have already tested my roleFilter with ldapsearch and it works. Thus, I assume that the authentification against the LDAP server (in my case Active Directory) does not work.

Can anyone give some advice please? What could be the problem?

This is a part of the **activemq.log** file

```
 | org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,532 | DEBUG | HttpConnection@1b2b26a5::DecryptedEndPoint@3598522{l=/******.43:8162,r=/******.227:57463,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=26180/30000} parsed true HttpParser{s=CONTENT,0 of -1} | org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,533 | DEBUG | releaseRequestBuffer HttpConnection@1b2b26a5::DecryptedEndPoint@3598522{l=/******.43:8162,r=/******.227:57463,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=26181/30000} | org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,534 | DEBUG | handle //******.43:8162/admin/ HttpChannelOverHttp@e0c6f57{s=HttpChannelState@6b48aaa5{s=IDLE rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=2,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=//******.43:8162/admin/,age=3}  | org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,535 | DEBUG | handling HttpChannelState@6b48aaa5{s=IDLE rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0} | org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannelState | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,535 | DEBUG | action DISPATCH HttpChannelOverHttp@e0c6f57{s=HttpChannelState@6b48aaa5{s=HANDLING rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=2,c=false/false,a=HANDLING,uri=//******.43:8162/admin/,age=4} | org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,536 | DEBUG | Host ******.43 with SNI null | org.eclipse.jetty.server.SecureRequestCustomizer | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,537 | DEBUG | REQUEST GET /admin/ on HttpChannelOverHttp@e0c6f57{s=HttpChannelState@6b48aaa5{s=HANDLING rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=2,c=false/false,a=HANDLING,uri=https://******.43:8162/admin/,age=6} | org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,601 | DEBUG | sendError HttpChannelState@6b48aaa5{s=HANDLING rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0} | org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannelState | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,603 | DEBUG | handled=true async=false committed=true on HttpChannelOverHttp@e0c6f57{s=HttpChannelState@6b48aaa5{s=HANDLING rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=true i=true al=0},r=2,c=false/false,a=HANDLING,uri=https://******.43:8162/admin/,age=72} | org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,604 | DEBUG | unhandle HttpChannelState@6b48aaa5{s=HANDLING rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=true i=true al=0} | org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannelState | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,604 | DEBUG | nextAction(false) SEND_ERROR HttpChannelState@6b48aaa5{s=HANDLING rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=false al=0} | org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannelState | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,605 | DEBUG | action SEND_ERROR HttpChannelOverHttp@e0c6f57{s=HttpChannelState@6b48aaa5{s=HANDLING rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=false al=0},r=2,c=false/false,a=HANDLING,uri=https://******.43:8162/admin/,age=74} | org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,606 | DEBUG | >fill SslConnection@5d25e0f2::SocketChannelEndPoint@570c0598{l=/******.43:8162,r=/******.227:57463,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=120/30000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}->SslConnection@5d25e0f2{NOT_HANDSHAKING,eio=-1/-1,di=-1,fill=IDLE,flush=IDLE}~>DecryptedEndPoint@3598522{l=/******.43:8162,r=/******.227:57463,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=26254/30000}=>HttpConnection@1b2b26a5[p=HttpParser{s=CONTENT,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@7bfcb0a7{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@e0c6f57{s=HttpChannelState@6b48aaa5{s=HANDLING rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=false al=0},r=2,c=false/false,a=HANDLING,uri=https://******.43:8162/admin/,age=75} | org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,607 | DEBUG | fill NOT_HANDSHAKING | org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,608 | DEBUG | filled 0 HeapByteBuffer@723d2a39[p=0,l=0,c=17408,r=0]={<<<>>>\x17\x03\x03\x02\x7fGET ...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00} | org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,609 | DEBUG | net filled=0 | org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,610 | DEBUG | unwrap net_filled=0 Status = BUFFER_UNDERFLOW HandshakeStatus = NOT_HANDSHAKING bytesConsumed = 0 bytesProduced = 0 encryptedBuffer=[p=0,l=0,c=17408,r=0] unwrapBuffer=HeapByteBuffer@2268d6c[p=0,l=0,c=17408,r=0]={<<<>>>GET /admi...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00} appBuffer=HeapByteBuffer@2268d6c[p=0,l=0,c=17408,r=0]={<<<>>>GET /admi...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00} | org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,611 | DEBUG | <fill f=0 uf=true SslConnection@5d25e0f2::SocketChannelEndPoint@570c0598{l=/******.43:8162,r=/******.227:57463,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=124/30000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}->SslConnection@5d25e0f2{NOT_HANDSHAKING,eio=-1/-1,di=-1,fill=IDLE,flush=IDLE}~>DecryptedEndPoint@3598522{l=/******.43:8162,r=/******.227:57463,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=26259/30000}=>HttpConnection@1b2b26a5[p=HttpParser{s=CONTENT,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@7bfcb0a7{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@e0c6f57{s=HttpChannelState@6b48aaa5{s=HANDLING rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=false al=0},r=2,c=false/false,a=HANDLING,uri=https://******.43:8162/admin/,age=80} | org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,612 | DEBUG | >fill SslConnection@5d25e0f2::SocketChannelEndPoint@570c0598{l=/******.43:8162,r=/******.227:57463,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=125/30000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}->SslConnection@5d25e0f2{NOT_HANDSHAKING,eio=-1/-1,di=-1,fill=IDLE,flush=IDLE}~>DecryptedEndPoint@3598522{l=/******.43:8162,r=/******.227:57463,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=26260/30000}=>HttpConnection@1b2b26a5[p=HttpParser{s=CONTENT,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@7bfcb0a7{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@e0c6f57{s=HttpChannelState@6b48aaa5{s=HANDLING rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=false al=0},r=2,c=false/false,a=HANDLING,uri=https://******.43:8162/admin/,age=81} | org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,613 | DEBUG | fill NOT_HANDSHAKING | org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,614 | DEBUG | filled 0 HeapByteBuffer@723d2a39[p=0,l=0,c=17408,r=0]={<<<>>>\x17\x03\x03\x02\x7fGET ...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00} | org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,614 | DEBUG | net filled=0 | org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,615 | DEBUG | unwrap net_filled=0 Status = BUFFER_UNDERFLOW HandshakeStatus = NOT_HANDSHAKING bytesConsumed = 0 bytesProduced = 0 encryptedBuffer=[p=0,l=0,c=17408,r=0] unwrapBuffer=HeapByteBuffer@2268d6c[p=0,l=0,c=17408,r=0]={<<<>>>GET /admi...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00} appBuffer=HeapByteBuffer@2268d6c[p=0,l=0,c=17408,r=0]={<<<>>>GET /admi...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00} | org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,616 | DEBUG | <fill f=0 uf=true SslConnection@5d25e0f2::SocketChannelEndPoint@570c0598{l=/******.43:8162,r=/******.227:57463,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=129/30000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}->SslConnection@5d25e0f2{NOT_HANDSHAKING,eio=-1/-1,di=-1,fill=IDLE,flush=IDLE}~>DecryptedEndPoint@3598522{l=/******.43:8162,r=/******.227:57463,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=26264/30000}=>HttpConnection@1b2b26a5[p=HttpParser{s=CONTENT,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@7bfcb0a7{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@e0c6f57{s=HttpChannelState@6b48aaa5{s=HANDLING rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=false al=0},r=2,c=false/false,a=HANDLING,uri=https://******.43:8162/admin/,age=85} | org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,617 | DEBUG | HttpConnection@1b2b26a5::DecryptedEndPoint@3598522{l=/******.43:8162,r=/******.227:57463,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=26265/30000} filled 0 HeapByteBuffer@2268d6c[p=0,l=0,c=17408,r=0]={<<<>>>GET /admi...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00} | org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,618 | DEBUG | HttpConnection@1b2b26a5::DecryptedEndPoint@3598522{l=/******.43:8162,r=/******.227:57463,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=26266/30000} parse HeapByteBuffer@2268d6c[p=0,l=0,c=17408,r=0]={<<<>>>GET /admi...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00} {} | org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,619 | DEBUG | parseNext s=CONTENT HeapByteBuffer@2268d6c[p=0,l=0,c=17408,r=0]={<<<>>>GET /admi...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00} | org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,620 | DEBUG | CONTENT --> CONTENT_END | org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,621 | DEBUG | onContentComplete HttpChannelOverHttp@e0c6f57{s=HttpChannelState@6b48aaa5{s=HANDLING rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=false al=0},r=2,c=false/false,a=HANDLING,uri=https://******.43:8162/admin/,age=89} | org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,621 | DEBUG | CONTENT_END --> END | org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,622 | DEBUG | onRequestComplete HttpChannelOverHttp@e0c6f57{s=HttpChannelState@6b48aaa5{s=HANDLING rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=false al=0},r=2,c=false/false,a=HANDLING,uri=https://******.43:8162/admin/,age=91} | org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,623 | DEBUG | HttpInputOverHTTP@7dc5363c[c=0,q=0,[0]=null,s=STREAM] addContent EOF | org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,624 | DEBUG | HttpConnection@1b2b26a5::DecryptedEndPoint@3598522{l=/******.43:8162,r=/******.227:57463,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=26272/30000} parsed false HttpParser{s=END,0 of -1} | org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,625 | DEBUG | releaseRequestBuffer HttpConnection@1b2b26a5::DecryptedEndPoint@3598522{l=/******.43:8162,r=/******.227:57463,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=26273/30000} | org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,627 | DEBUG | completing HttpChannelState@6b48aaa5{s=HANDLING rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=false al=0} | org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannelState | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,627 | DEBUG | sendResponse info=null content=HeapByteBuffer@3438f4f9[p=0,l=453,c=32768,r=453]={<<<<html>\n<head>\n<meta http-...<hr/>\n\n</body>\n</html>\n>>>\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00} complete=true committing=true callback=org.eclipse.jetty.util.Callback$3@4e7f70d8 | org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,628 | DEBUG | COMMIT for /admin/ on HttpChannelOverHttp@e0c6f57{s=HttpChannelState@6b48aaa5{s=HANDLING rs=COMPLETING os=COMMITTED is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=false al=0},r=2,c=false/false,a=HANDLING,uri=https://******.43:8162/admin/,age=97}
401 null HTTP/1.1
WWW-Authenticate: basic realm="LdapRealm"
Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
Content-Type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1

 | org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,629 | DEBUG | generate: NEED_HEADER for SendCallback@734cc921[PROCESSING][i=HTTP/1.1{s=401,h=3,cl=-1},cb=org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel$SendCallback@2fdeb92c] (null,[p=0,l=453,c=32768,r=453],true)@START | org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,630 | DEBUG | generateHeaders HTTP/1.1{s=401,h=3,cl=-1} last=true content=HeapByteBuffer@3438f4f9[p=0,l=453,c=32768,r=453]={<<<<html>\n<head>\n<meta http-...<hr/>\n\n</body>\n</html>\n>>>\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00} | org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,631 | DEBUG | WWW-Authenticate: basic realm="LdapRealm"
Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
Content-Type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1

 | org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,632 | DEBUG | CONTENT_LENGTH | org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,633 | DEBUG | generate: FLUSH for SendCallback@734cc921[PROCESSING][i=HTTP/1.1{s=401,h=3,cl=-1},cb=org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel$SendCallback@2fdeb92c] ([p=0,l=220,c=8192,r=220],[p=0,l=453,c=32768,r=453],true)@COMPLETING | org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,634 | DEBUG | write: WriteFlusher@74cd500e{IDLE}->null [HeapByteBuffer@25d2657a[p=0,l=220,c=8192,r=220]={<<<HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized...y(9.4.39.v20210325)\r\n\r\n>>>Accept-Ra...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00},HeapByteBuffer@3438f4f9[p=0,l=453,c=32768,r=453]={<<<<html>\n<head>\n<meta http-...<hr/>\n\n</body>\n</html>\n>>>\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00}] | org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,635 | DEBUG | update WriteFlusher@74cd500e{WRITING}->null:IDLE-->WRITING | org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,636 | DEBUG | >flush SslConnection@5d25e0f2::SocketChannelEndPoint@570c0598{l=/******.43:8162,r=/******.227:57463,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=149/30000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}->SslConnection@5d25e0f2{NOT_HANDSHAKING,eio=-1/-1,di=-1,fill=IDLE,flush=IDLE}~>DecryptedEndPoint@3598522{l=/******.43:8162,r=/******.227:57463,OPEN,fill=-,flush=W,to=26284/30000}=>HttpConnection@1b2b26a5[p=HttpParser{s=END,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@7bfcb0a7{s=COMPLETING}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@e0c6f57{s=HttpChannelState@6b48aaa5{s=HANDLING rs=COMPLETING os=COMMITTED is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=false al=0},r=2,c=false/false,a=HANDLING,uri=https://******.43:8162/admin/,age=105} | org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,637 | DEBUG | flush b[0]=HeapByteBuffer@25d2657a[p=0,l=220,c=8192,r=220]={<<<HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized...y(9.4.39.v20210325)\r\n\r\n>>>Accept-Ra...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00} | org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,638 | DEBUG | flush b[1]=HeapByteBuffer@3438f4f9[p=0,l=453,c=32768,r=453]={<<<<html>\n<head>\n<meta http-...<hr/>\n\n</body>\n</html>\n>>>\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00} | org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,639 | DEBUG | flush NOT_HANDSHAKING | org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,640 | DEBUG | wrap Status = OK HandshakeStatus = NOT_HANDSHAKING bytesConsumed = 673 bytesProduced = 695 sequenceNumber = 2 [p=0,l=695,c=17408,r=695] ioDone=false/false | org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,641 | DEBUG | flushed 695 SocketChannelEndPoint@570c0598{l=/******.43:8162,r=/******.227:57463,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=154/30000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}->SslConnection@5d25e0f2{NOT_HANDSHAKING,eio=-1/0,di=-1,fill=IDLE,flush=IDLE}~>DecryptedEndPoint@3598522{l=/******.43:8162,r=/******.227:57463,OPEN,fill=-,flush=W,to=26289/30000}=>HttpConnection@1b2b26a5[p=HttpParser{s=END,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@7bfcb0a7{s=COMPLETING}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@e0c6f57{s=HttpChannelState@6b48aaa5{s=HANDLING rs=COMPLETING os=COMMITTED is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=false al=0},r=2,c=false/false,a=HANDLING,uri=https://******.43:8162/admin/,age=110} | org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,642 | DEBUG | net flushed=true, ac=true | org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,643 | DEBUG | <flush true SslConnection@5d25e0f2::SocketChannelEndPoint@570c0598{l=/******.43:8162,r=/******.227:57463,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=0/30000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}->SslConnection@5d25e0f2{NOT_HANDSHAKING,eio=-1/-1,di=-1,fill=IDLE,flush=IDLE}~>DecryptedEndPoint@3598522{l=/******.43:8162,r=/******.227:57463,OPEN,fill=-,flush=W,to=26291/30000}=>HttpConnection@1b2b26a5[p=HttpParser{s=END,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@7bfcb0a7{s=COMPLETING}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@e0c6f57{s=HttpChannelState@6b48aaa5{s=HANDLING rs=COMPLETING os=COMMITTED is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=false al=0},r=2,c=false/false,a=HANDLING,uri=https://******.43:8162/admin/,age=112} | org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,644 | DEBUG | Flushed=true written=673 remaining=0 WriteFlusher@74cd500e{WRITING}->null | org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,644 | DEBUG | update WriteFlusher@74cd500e{IDLE}->null:WRITING-->IDLE | org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,645 | DEBUG | generate: DONE for SendCallback@734cc921[PROCESSING][i=HTTP/1.1{s=401,h=3,cl=-1},cb=org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel$SendCallback@2fdeb92c] ([p=220,l=220,c=8192,r=0],[p=453,l=453,c=32768,r=0],true)@END | org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,646 | DEBUG | completed HttpChannelState@6b48aaa5{s=HANDLING rs=COMPLETING os=COMPLETED is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=false al=0} | org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannelState | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,647 | DEBUG | unhandle HttpChannelState@6b48aaa5{s=HANDLING rs=COMPLETED os=COMPLETED is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=false al=0} | org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannelState | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,648 | DEBUG | nextAction(false) TERMINATED HttpChannelState@6b48aaa5{s=IDLE rs=COMPLETED os=COMPLETED is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=false al=0} | org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannelState | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,649 | DEBUG | action TERMINATED HttpChannelOverHttp@e0c6f57{s=HttpChannelState@6b48aaa5{s=IDLE rs=COMPLETED os=COMPLETED is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=false al=0},r=2,c=true/true,a=IDLE,uri=https://******.43:8162/admin/,age=118} | org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,650 | DEBUG | onCompleted for /admin/ written=453 | org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,651 | DEBUG | recycle HttpChannelState@6b48aaa5{s=IDLE rs=COMPLETED os=COMPLETED is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=false al=0} | org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannelState | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,651 | DEBUG | reset HttpParser{s=END,0 of -1} | org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,652 | DEBUG | END --> START | org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,653 | DEBUG | !handle TERMINATED HttpChannelOverHttp@e0c6f57{s=HttpChannelState@6b48aaa5{s=IDLE rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=2,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0} | org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,654 | DEBUG | >fill SslConnection@5d25e0f2::SocketChannelEndPoint@570c0598{l=/******.43:8162,r=/******.227:57463,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=12/30000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}->SslConnection@5d25e0f2{NOT_HANDSHAKING,eio=-1/-1,di=-1,fill=IDLE,flush=IDLE}~>DecryptedEndPoint@3598522{l=/******.43:8162,r=/******.227:57463,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=26302/30000}=>HttpConnection@1b2b26a5[p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@7bfcb0a7{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@e0c6f57{s=HttpChannelState@6b48aaa5{s=IDLE rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=2,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0} | org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,655 | DEBUG | fill NOT_HANDSHAKING | org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,656 | DEBUG | filled 0 HeapByteBuffer@723d2a39[p=0,l=0,c=17408,r=0]={<<<>>>\x17\x03\x03\x02\x7fGET ...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00} | org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,657 | DEBUG | net filled=0 | org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,657 | DEBUG | unwrap net_filled=0 Status = BUFFER_UNDERFLOW HandshakeStatus = NOT_HANDSHAKING bytesConsumed = 0 bytesProduced = 0 encryptedBuffer=[p=0,l=0,c=17408,r=0] unwrapBuffer=HeapByteBuffer@2268d6c[p=0,l=0,c=17408,r=0]={<<<>>>\x17\x03\x03\x02\xB2\x94 \xFc\xDd...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00} appBuffer=HeapByteBuffer@2268d6c[p=0,l=0,c=17408,r=0]={<<<>>>\x17\x03\x03\x02\xB2\x94 \xFc\xDd...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00} | org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,658 | DEBUG | <fill f=0 uf=true SslConnection@5d25e0f2::SocketChannelEndPoint@570c0598{l=/******.43:8162,r=/******.227:57463,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=16/30000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}->SslConnection@5d25e0f2{NOT_HANDSHAKING,eio=-1/-1,di=-1,fill=IDLE,flush=IDLE}~>DecryptedEndPoint@3598522{l=/******.43:8162,r=/******.227:57463,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=26306/30000}=>HttpConnection@1b2b26a5[p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@7bfcb0a7{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@e0c6f57{s=HttpChannelState@6b48aaa5{s=IDLE rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=2,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0} | org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,659 | DEBUG | >fill SslConnection@5d25e0f2::SocketChannelEndPoint@570c0598{l=/******.43:8162,r=/******.227:57463,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=17/30000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}->SslConnection@5d25e0f2{NOT_HANDSHAKING,eio=-1/-1,di=-1,fill=IDLE,flush=IDLE}~>DecryptedEndPoint@3598522{l=/******.43:8162,r=/******.227:57463,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=26307/30000}=>HttpConnection@1b2b26a5[p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@7bfcb0a7{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@e0c6f57{s=HttpChannelState@6b48aaa5{s=IDLE rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=2,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0} | org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,660 | DEBUG | fill NOT_HANDSHAKING | org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,661 | DEBUG | filled 0 HeapByteBuffer@723d2a39[p=0,l=0,c=17408,r=0]={<<<>>>\x17\x03\x03\x02\x7fGET ...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00} | org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,662 | DEBUG | net filled=0 | org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,663 | DEBUG | unwrap net_filled=0 Status = BUFFER_UNDERFLOW HandshakeStatus = NOT_HANDSHAKING bytesConsumed = 0 bytesProduced = 0 encryptedBuffer=[p=0,l=0,c=17408,r=0] unwrapBuffer=HeapByteBuffer@2268d6c[p=0,l=0,c=17408,r=0]={<<<>>>\x17\x03\x03\x02\xB2\x94 \xFc\xDd...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00} appBuffer=HeapByteBuffer@2268d6c[p=0,l=0,c=17408,r=0]={<<<>>>\x17\x03\x03\x02\xB2\x94 \xFc\xDd...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00} | org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,664 | DEBUG | <fill f=0 uf=true SslConnection@5d25e0f2::SocketChannelEndPoint@570c0598{l=/******.43:8162,r=/******.227:57463,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=21/30000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}->SslConnection@5d25e0f2{NOT_HANDSHAKING,eio=-1/-1,di=-1,fill=IDLE,flush=IDLE}~>DecryptedEndPoint@3598522{l=/******.43:8162,r=/******.227:57463,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=26312/30000}=>HttpConnection@1b2b26a5[p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@7bfcb0a7{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@e0c6f57{s=HttpChannelState@6b48aaa5{s=IDLE rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=2,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0} | org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,665 | DEBUG | HttpConnection@1b2b26a5::DecryptedEndPoint@3598522{l=/******.43:8162,r=/******.227:57463,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=26312/30000} filled 0 HeapByteBuffer@2268d6c[p=0,l=0,c=17408,r=0]={<<<>>>\x17\x03\x03\x02\xB2\x94 \xFc\xDd...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00} | org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,665 | DEBUG | HttpConnection@1b2b26a5::DecryptedEndPoint@3598522{l=/******.43:8162,r=/******.227:57463,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=26313/30000} parse HeapByteBuffer@2268d6c[p=0,l=0,c=17408,r=0]={<<<>>>\x17\x03\x03\x02\xB2\x94 \xFc\xDd...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00} {} | org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,666 | DEBUG | parseNext s=START HeapByteBuffer@2268d6c[p=0,l=0,c=17408,r=0]={<<<>>>\x17\x03\x03\x02\xB2\x94 \xFc\xDd...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00} | org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,667 | DEBUG | HttpConnection@1b2b26a5::DecryptedEndPoint@3598522{l=/******.43:8162,r=/******.227:57463,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=26315/30000} parsed false HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1} | org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,668 | DEBUG | releaseRequestBuffer HttpConnection@1b2b26a5::DecryptedEndPoint@3598522{l=/******.43:8162,r=/******.227:57463,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=26316/30000} | org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,669 | DEBUG | fillInterested HttpConnection@1b2b26a5::DecryptedEndPoint@3598522{l=/******.43:8162,r=/******.227:57463,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=26317/30000} | org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection | qtp1517251756-39
2022-01-17 14:41:55,670 | DEBUG | interested FillInterest@5f18058d{AC.ReadCB@1b2b26a5{HttpConnection@1b2b26a5::DecryptedEndPoint@3598522{l=/******.43:8162,r=/******.227:57463,OPEN,fill=FI,flush=-,to=0/30000}}} | org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest | qtp1517251756-39
```